# Elastic beanstalk is not responding with installed SSL

Tags: django, python-3.x, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app in AWS elastic beanstalk. Currently, I am trying to setup SSL in the environment. After setting up a below configuration both http and https are failing. I am following the below tutorial

https://github.com/lucasdf/demo-lets-encrypt-elastic-beanstalk/blob/master/ssl.config

SSL.conf :

````
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem"

        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/xxx/wsgi/__init__.py

        <Directory /opt/python/current/app>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
          python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages \
          home=/opt/python/current/app \
          user=wsgi \
          group=wsgi
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl

      </VirtualHost>
      <VirtualHost *:80>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
      </VirtualHost>                                                                                                                        ```
````

Comment: https://www.mattbutton.com/2018/08/06/enabling-https-on-elastic-beanstalk-without-a-load-balancer/

Comment: I am following the same link but it does not work.

Comment: Have you watched the logs on EC2 instance?

Comment: There is no error in the logs. Browser is showing "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Could you telnet port 80 and 443 from your PC to EC2 instance? Also check netstat -a on your EC2 instance. Are these ports open?